# A Set Theory Proof

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$A \triangle C = B \triangle C$ then $A = B$.

I am a bit stuck because how can I show that both $A$ and $B$ relate since as I see it, they only relate to $C$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy but tricky proof:

$$A\mathrel{\triangle}C=B\mathrel{\triangle}C\implies A=(A\mathrel{\triangle}C)\mathrel{\triangle}C=(B\mathrel{\triangle}C)\mathrel{\triangle}C=B$$

because $A\mathrel{\triangle}C\mathrel{\triangle}C=A$ for any $A,C$. (The easiest way to show this without any involved calculations is to identify the operation $x\in A\mathrel{\triangle}B$ with the modular sum $a\oplus b:=(a+b)\bmod 2$, so that $a\oplus b\oplus b=a\oplus 2b=a\oplus0=a$.)

Answer (score 3):

HINT: Suppose that $x\in A\setminus B$. There are two possibilities to consider: $x\in C$, and $x\notin C$.

- If $x\in C$, is $x\in A\mathrel{\triangle}C$? Is $x\in B\mathrel{\triangle}C$?
- If $x\notin C$, is $x\in A\mathrel{\triangle}C$? Is $x\in B\mathrel{\triangle}C$?

Then ask yourself the same questions if $x\in B\setminus A$.